# Exporting zipped folder only with csv content

Tags: python, export-to-csv, zip, cx-oracle

1.I am using Oracle and the idea is to use python script to export tables as zipped folder containing csv file which holds my data.

2.Additionaly: Is it possible to save this data in csv per columns. For example, I have 4 columns and all of them are stored in 1 column in csv.
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF3CV.jpg)

This is my script:

```
import os
import cx_Oracle
import csv
import zipfile

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('dbconnection')
SQL = "SELECT * FROM AIR_CONDITIONS_YEARLY_MVIEW ORDER BY TIME"

filename = "sample.csv"

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(SQL)
with open (filename, 'r') as output:
   writer = csv.writer (output)
   writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description])
   writer.writerows(cursor.fetchall())
air_zip = zipfile.ZipFile("sample.zip", 'w')
air_zip.write(filename, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

cursor.close()
connection.close()
air_zip.close()
```

Code I did exports me separately both csv and zipped folder with proper csv file inside and I want to keep exporting this zipped folder only!
[Both sample.zip containing sample.csv as expected and sample.csv generated at the same time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NRQY.jpg)

Comment: So you want to remove *sample.csv* after it's being archived?

Comment: @CristiFati let's say i dont even need it archived, only in zipped folder..removal would be useful as well if it doesnt use memory

Comment: So there are multiple problems here. The *.csv* file is generated *OK* (you mentioned something about columns)?  Could you post a sample (the header and the first 2 rows)? Now regarding the archive. You have *sample.zip* which contains (the above *sample.csv*). What is wrong with this? What would you like the zip file to contain?

Comment: @CristiFati Sorry, I ve uploaded an image now. My sample.zip contains sample.csv what is perfect but beside this exported file i get sample.csv too. So I get sample.zip ( with sample.csv inside) and sample.csv.I only want to export sample.zip which has sample.csv in it

Comment: I think that the *.csv* file is *OK*, but it's rather the way how *Excel* interprets it. Check https://superuser.com/questions/606272/how-to-get-excel-to-interpret-the-comma-as-a-default-delimiter-in-csv-files, and let me know what the results are. Then we'll move on to the other issue.

Comment: @CristiFati as you said its the way how Excel interprets it...i changed regional settings but the output was much worse so I'll stick to my solution.Only in case the customer really, really wants it "tabular", colon per colon and row per row ;-)

Comment: You can also test your csv by pasting (the first part of) its contents (open it with Notepad) in an online csv viewer (https://www.google.ro/search?newwindow=1&hl=en-RO&authuser=0&ei=QPQ1XNLZB5Ok1fAPtvCJuAs&q=online+csv+viewer&oq=online+csv+&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0l10.2328227.2330595..2331121...0.0..0.98.1031.11......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i67j0i203.n57mFB5BVnE). Does it look right there?

Comment: @CristiFati in this online editor it looks perfect!  so its definetely the way excel wants to see it. I will keep it as it is so its "solved"....Mystery that is remaining is to exclude sample.csv from my export along with preferable sample.zip (containing sample.csv)  Hopefully I am clear enough :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a list of problems:

- The *.csv* file is not properly formatted (a row is seen as a single record (string) instead of a sequence of records):

  - Looking (blindly) at the code and tools (`csv.writer`, *cx_Oracle*) documentation, it seems correct
  - When noticing that the file is opened with *Excel*, I remembered that at some point I had a similar issue. A quick search yielded [[SuperUser]: How to get Excel to interpret the comma as a default delimiter in CSV files?](https://superuser.com/questions/606272/how-to-get-excel-to-interpret-the-comma-as-a-default-delimiter-in-csv-files)
    . And this was the culprit (the *.csv* file looks fine in an online viewer / editor)
- Code "*exporting*" both *.csv* and *.zip* files (I don't know what *export* means, I assume *generate* - meaning that after running the code, both files are present):

  - The way of getting around this is by deleting the *.csv* file **after** it was archived into the *.zip* file. Translated into code that would mean adding at the end of the current script snippet:

    ```
    os.unlink(filename)
    ```

As a final observation (if one wants to be pedantic), the lines that close the cursor and the databbase could be moved just after the ***with*** block or before *air_zip* creation (there's no point keeping them open while archiving).

Comment: problem solved with os.unlink() and slightly modified to be more pedantic ;-) Cheers mate!